# How to find the index of repeats in a 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array, how I can find the index of all repeats in this array ?
For example, the data looks like this,

```
array([[116.366 ,  39.8673],[116.17  ,  40.2865],...[112.5628,  37.8964]]),
```

if the first and third are the same, 
the second and fourth are the same, then the return value should be like `[[1,3],[2,4]]`.

Comment: this ain't enough to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from a little correction of your task: As the source array is
**2-dimensional**, each element has **two** indices, so if an element occurs
multiple times, the result for this element should be a list of **pairs**
(row / column) - which elements have this value.

And as far as the code is concerned, let's start from import and creation
of a source array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

tbl = np.array([[116.3, 39.8], [116.1, 40.2],  [40.2, 116.3], [112.5, 37.8]])
```

As you can see, we have 4 rows and 2 columns, where `116.3` and  `40.2` occur twice.

Then we have to generate data for a DataFrame (value and indices for each element).
To do this, we can use `np.nditer` function:

```
tbl2 = []
it = np.nditer(tbl, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    tbl2.append([float(it[0]), it.multi_index])
    it.iternext()
```

Explicit casting (accordingly to your data, to `float`) is needed,
because otherwise the iterator returns 0-dimensional NumPy arrays,
which are not hashable, what causes problems later.

Then we create a `DataFrame` with proper column names (element and its
indices):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=tbl2, columns=['elem', 'indices'])
```

And the last point is to create the result:

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['elem'], keep=False)]\
    .groupby('elem')['indices'].apply(list)
```

The output (for the above data) is:

```
elem
40.2     [(1, 1), (2, 0)]
116.3    [(0, 0), (2, 1)]
Name: indices, dtype: object
```

The result is actually a Pandas *Series*, with key named `elem` (element value)
and the value is a list of tuples - indices of particular element in the
source array.

If you are interested **only** in indices of non-unique elements,
save the above result under e.g. `result` variable and add:

```
[y for x in result for y in x]
```

Then the output will be:

```
[(1, 1), (2, 0), (0, 0), (2, 1)]
```